# Remove inexistance files in logs Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

So in my log file of my symfony project I have errors for inexistant files then after a small time I have a big log file > 50 Mb,I don't know what I can do to resolve this problem??I never work with this kind of problem?

Comment: Maybe you should use this task : http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks#chapter_16_sub_log_rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> php symfony log:rotate [--history="..."] [--period="..."] application env

You can find this documented at:
http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks

On Unix's, you can run this as a cron job, with the same formatting that you would do for any task.